# Why is this postgresql text_pattern_ops index not used inside of a function body?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.6

I've created and populated a Postgres 9.6 table with this code

```sql
create table text_table(id serial primary key , value text);

create index on text_table(lower(value) text_pattern_ops);

insert into text_table(value)
    select md5(random()::text)
    from generate_series(0, 1000000);

create or replace function search_text_table(term text) returns table(id int) as $$
begin
    return query (select text_table.id from text_table where lower(value) like term);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

-- Query 1
explain analyze select t.id from text_table t where lower(t.value) like 'aba%';
-- Query 2
explain analyze select id from search_text_table('aba%');
```

In the first query, the index on `value` is used to speed up the query:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on text_table t  (cost=216.95..8600.17 rows=5500 width=4) (actual time=0.162..0.798 rows=250 loops=1)
  Filter: (lower(value) ~~ 'aba%'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on text_table_lower_idx  (cost=0.00..215.57 rows=5500 width=0) (actual time=0.094..0.094 rows=250 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((lower(value) ~>=~ 'aba'::text) AND (lower(value) ~<~ 'abb'::text))
Total runtime: 0.833 ms
```

However, when the same code is executed as part of the `search_text_table` function, I'm presuming that the index isn't used as the query takes three orders of magnitude more time to run:

```
Function Scan on search_text_table  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=985.031..992.106 rows=68625 loops=1)
Total runtime: 994.515 ms
```

Why is Postgres not using the index when the term supplied to the `like` operator is a function parameter and not a constant string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce that, but I suspect that you did something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE text_table(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   value text
);
CREATE INDEX ON text_table(lower(value) text_pattern_ops);

INSERT INTO text_table(value)
    SELECT md5(random()::text)
    FROM generate_series(0, 1000000);

CREATE FUNCTION search_text_table(term text)
   RETURNS TABLE(id int) AS
$$BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY (SELECT text_table.id
                FROM text_table
                WHERE lower(value) LIKE term);
END;$$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- repeat a query like this 5 times
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('%abc%');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('%abc%');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('%abc%');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('%abc%');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('%abc%');
-- then run a query that could use the index
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');
```

Let's see what PostgreSQL really does:

```
-- requires being superuser
LOAD 'auto_explain';
SET log_min_messages = panic;
SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on;
SET client_min_messages = log;
SET auto_explain.log_analyze = on;

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');

LOG:  duration: 2033.747 ms  plan:
Query Text: (select text_table.id from text_table where lower(value) like term)
Seq Scan on text_table  (cost=0.00..23334.01 rows=5000 width=4) (actual time=4.374..2033.395 rows=246 loops=1)
  Filter: (lower(value) ~~ $1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 999755

LOG:  duration: 2034.259 ms  plan:
Query Text: explain analyze select id from search_text_table('abc%');
Function Scan on search_text_table  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=2034.209..2034.240 rows=246 loops=1)
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on search_text_table  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=2034.209..2034.240 rows=246 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.194 ms
 Execution time: 2034.353 ms
(3 rows)
```

During the first 5 executions, PostgreSQL will use a *custom plan*, that is, it will create a plan for the statement with the actual parameter value.

At the sixth execution, it checks if the plan chosen during the previous 5 executions was better than the *generic plan*, the plan without knowing the parameter value. I crafted my example so that it wasn't, so PostgreSQL decides to use the generic plan from now on.

That means that regardless of the argument, it will use a sequential scan. You can see the generic plan in the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output — note the `$1`.

---

If you do the experiment like you showed it, something different will happen.

Terminate the PostgreSQL connection and start a new one so that PostgreSQL will lose all its cached query plans.

Then try again like this:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');

-- requires being superuser
LOAD 'auto_explain';
SET log_min_messages = panic;
SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on;
SET client_min_messages = log;
SET auto_explain.log_analyze = on;

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');

LOG:  duration: 5.123 ms  plan:
Query Text: (select text_table.id from text_table where lower(value) like term)
Bitmap Heap Scan on text_table  (cost=4.62..70.57 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.272..4.889 rows=246 loops=1)
  Filter: (lower(value) ~~ 'abc%'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=242
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on text_table_lower_idx  (cost=0.00..4.59 rows=17 width=0) (actual time=0.184..0.184 rows=246 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((lower(value) ~>=~ 'abc'::text) AND (lower(value) ~<~ 'abd'::text))

LOG:  duration: 6.289 ms  plan:
Query Text: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT id FROM search_text_table('abc%');
Function Scan on search_text_table  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=6.220..6.264 rows=246 loops=1)
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on search_text_table  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=6.220..6.264 rows=246 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.055 ms
 Execution time: 6.398 ms
(3 rows)
```

This time the custom plan during the first 5 executions was better than the generic plan with its sequential scan, so PostgreSQL continues to use custom plans for the following executions.

---

From PostgreSQL v12 on, you'll be able to control this behavior with the parameter `plan_cache_mode`.

Comment: Think I've resolved it by modifying the function that searches to follow the same form each time - by appending a '%' to the query. The actual problem this came from is doing prefix searching, so by making sure that the '%' always comes at the end, it is performing quickly.

Comment: Right, because then PostgreSQL won't choose the generic plan.